# Let $T:\mathbb{P_2}\rightarrow\mathbb{P_2}$ be a linear transformation defined by $T(a+bt+ct^2)=3a+(5a-2b)t+(4b+c)t^2$

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb{P_2}\rightarrow\mathbb{P_2}$ be a linear transformation defined by $T(a+bt+ct^2)=3a+(5a-2b)t+(4b+c)t^2$

Find the basis C for $\mathbb{P_2}$ so that the matrix $[T]_c$ is a digonal matrix

My attmept: Suppose we take basis of C is ${1, t, t^2}$ i am little confusing can any   help me to solve

Comment: Hint: Find the eigenvectors rather eigenfunctions for $T$.

Comment: You mean using Eigen vectors as basis? Since they are linearly independent? What if Eigen vector space dimension is less than 3?

Comment: i just assumed $\{1, t,t^2\}$  is basis but these are not the part of the question

Comment: @jnyan..we can find a basis so that the matrix is digonal

Comment: @rajendra Try finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors first instead of needlessly worrying about what to do if you have repeated eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find a basis $C=\{p_1,p_2, p_3\}$ of $\mathbb{P_2}$ and real numbers $t_1,t_2,t_3$ such that

$T(p_j)=t_jp_j$ for  $j=1,2,3$.

Then: $[T]_c=diag(t_1,t_2,t_3)$

FRED

Answer (score 0):

There are an infinite amount of basis. $e = (1,t,t^2)$ is just the obvious one.

Here is the matrix of T in $e$ :

$$[T]_e = \begin{pmatrix} 3&0&0 \\ 5&-2&0 \\ 0&4&1\end{pmatrix} $$

Can you find $e'$ so that $[T]_{e'}$ is a diagonal matrix ?

Comment: @Furarane..no i cant  find basis such that the matrix is digonal

Answer (score -1):

Do The following operations on the T matrix w.r.t standard basis. $ C'_2\,=  C_2 \, - \, 4. C_3\,\, \\\\\, C'_1 = \, 2. C_1-\,\,5.C'_2 $. to get a diagonal matrix. Do the same operation on standard basis matrix to obtain $ [2,\, 5+t,\,-20-4t+ t^2] $ as basis. This basis will give a diagonal matrix.

Comment: The matrix of $T$ in this basis is not diagonal. Essentially, you’ve computed a matrix $B$ such that $[T]_eB$ is diagonal, but what’s needed here is for $B^{-1}[T]_eB$ to be diagonal. Also, you’ve got a sign error in your column reduction steps.